# Error while deploying AWS Lambda S3 tutorial code

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am executing the AWS Lambda S3 tutorial from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

I have installed node.js v12 on an ec2 Amazon Linux v2 instance. After following all the instructions in the tutorial, I get the following error in the CloudWatch error logs.

```html
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
    "errorMessage": "SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>",
        "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:98:13)",
        "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:45:30)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)",
        "    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)",
        "    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)",
        "    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)"
    ]
}
```

The code is available on the tutorial page.

P.S.: The code was running properly when AWS lambda was supporting node.js v4 runtime. Hence I assume the error is due to some change in Syntax. I have searched the error string on google but did not find any relevant link.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is now resolved.
I was using the wrong aws region in input.txt file.